# Trying to understand the max_distance parameter in Spatial Join sjoin_nearest() GeoPandas Python

Tags: python, join, spatial, geopandas, shapely

I have two geopandas dataframe having Point and LineString Geometries.

I want to use spatial joins to combine these dataframes on the basis of the distance between them.

Following are the two geometrical columns I want to use for joining:

[Point Geometry]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPkQw.png)

[LineString]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIWs6.png)

I used sjoin_nearest() function in geopandas to join based on their distance.
Following is the line of code I am using for joining:

joined_df = point_gdf.sjoin_nearest(gdf,how='left',distance_col='distances',max_distance=0.06219)

Someone told me that the unit of max_distance is miles so I tried converting 100 meters to miles and then providing the value.

I get the following output:

[Joined Dataframe]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAi6K.png)

Now I am confused about the max_distance parameter in sjoin_nearest().

- What is its unit ? meters or miles ?
- I want to get geometries which are in distance of 100 meters. How can I do this ? I provided max_distance = 100 but still getting the same number of rows.
- Does this max_distance depends upon the distance parameter. distance column is in float decimals as you can see 0.002 0.0017 etc.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The distance is in the units of the coordinate system you are using.

By the coordinates it looks like [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326) which have

> Unit: degree (supplier to define representation)

You should not be measuring distances in degrees. 1 degree near the equator will be very different from 1 degree nearer the poles.

[Reproject](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) your data into a projected coordinate system with units in for example meters. Like one of the [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) zones.

If your data is in Saudi Arabia you can use [EPSG:9357](https://epsg.io/9357)